# Serving Amazon S3 Content by Amazon CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this code that updates the sql table to the files url´s when it´s backuped to amazon s3.

```
$sql = "update " . PVS_DB_PREFIX . "filestorage_files set filename1='" . $file .
       "',filename2='" . $new_filename . "',url='" . $url[0] .
       "',filesize=" . filesize( $publication_path .
       "/" . $file ) . ",width=" . $width . ",height=" . $height . 
       " where id_parent=" .
       $rs->row["id"] . " and item_id=" . $items_mass[$file];
       $db->execute( $sql );
```

Then i delete from local server the files that was moved to amazon s3 by:

```
//delete files from the local server
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $delete_mass ); $i++ ) {
    pvs_delete_files( ( int )$delete_mass[$i], false );
}
```

Now the files are on the Database with the Amazon S3 url but, i need it to be served on the front by Amazon CloudFront, so i will need to update da sql table again to update de url´s from the files moved to Amazon S3 by:

```
//cloud front update url on tumbs preview

$sql = "update " . PVS_DB_PREFIX .
       "filestorage_files set url='http://www.cloudfront.com/exmaple' item_id=" .
       $items_mass[$file] == 0;
$db->execute( $sql );
```

But... something here is not working right, can any one help me with this ?

Regard´s

Comment: Can you explain what is not working right? Update, or access to the file? What kind of error do you get? Also, did you put correct CF url ? (ie. is this just example so you hide true address, or is this real code?)

Comment: Hi, i have hiden the true cloudfront url. i have now fixed it by adding on db a new field, with the cloudfront url by default. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually the last part of your question not clear, but you should deploy a Cloudfront and set your S3 bucket as the origin. Finally, you have a unique URL for your published Cloudfront, and you can quickly add your file name after the main URL.

Comment: Hello! Right, but in this script i´m working on 2 storaged place, first the files are stored on local server, and will be moved next to the S3. I have fixes this by adding on DB, a new column "url2" to the CloudFront.